# Trying to save UiimageView but code is saving all of the page. In swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, swift3, uigraphicscontext

These 5 lines of code are saving the photo but they are saving the whole screen. Basically the save button is acting as a screen on a laptop. I have a uiimageView outlet that is where the imagepicker displays the photo. I just want uimmmageview to be saved and not the whole page.

My outlets name is cameraScreen. I have tried to insert in the code but it does not work. My app takes a photo and then puts a graphic on it as well.

Here is the code

```
import UIKit
class Camera:  UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,   UINavigationControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var cameraScreen: UIImageView!
    var screenView: UIImageView!


@IBAction func Camera(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera){
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera;
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)}}

            func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject: AnyObject]!){
                cameraScreen.image = image
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil);
                screenView = UIImageView()
                screenView.frame = CGRect(x:0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)



                    let text = "Java"
                    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 125, y: 400, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 300))
                    label.font = UIFont(name: label.font.fontName, size: 200)

                    label.textColor = UIColor.blue
                    label.alpha = 0.3
                    label.text = text

                    self.view.addSubview(screenView)
                    self.view.addSubview(label)



}

@IBAction func Save(_ sender: AnyObject) {





    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Image Saved", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let okay = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(okay)
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)




    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size)
   self.view.drawHierarchy(in: self.view.frame, afterScreenUpdates: true)
   let photo = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(photo!, nil, nil, nil)


}}
```

Comment: oddly familiar question - same issue (and maybe poorly coded line as yesterday's question. did you check this out: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40424554/how-to-save-only-uiimageview-not-the-whole-screen-in-my-photo-app-in-swift)

Comment: What do you mean it saves the whole page? A webpage?

Comment: When I say the whole page I mean the whole screen of the view controller. I just want it to save whatever pitcure is displayed in the uiimageview and not the whole screen. @i

Comment: @iOSwarrior my statement is above.

Comment: Why don't you explain what you are actually trying to do. Given the code you posted, all you need to do is pass `cameraScreen.image` to `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum`. Why are you trying to draw the whole view controller's view if all you want is the image view's image?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `self.cameraScreen` instead of `self.view`?

Comment: @rmaddy cameraScreen.image works exactly how I would like it to however the custom graphics text is not saved. I added all of the code above. Right now the code saves the picture as a screen shoot and the graphics are featured in the picture. I just want the cameraScreen.image to be saved but for the graphics to be in the picture. Thanks.

Comment: OK, so this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40424554/how-to-save-only-uiimageview-not-the-whole-screen-in-my-photo-app-in-swift. Why is this being posted again?

Comment: @rmaddy it is kind of a duplicate question but I change the saved function. You have to press the button for it to save.

Comment: Why repost under a new account? That's frowned upon here. Why don't you stick to one question and delete the other. Then you can keep one question up-to-date and not waste people's time spread across two questions.

Comment: @rmaddy thats my bad. Your right I am just trying to find the solution.